# Design a tree-like hierarchy of ownership classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a class, call it `App`, that will instantiate and own a set of classes of type `Agents`, each of which will instantiate and own a set of `Listeners`. Ownership is unique and non-transferable, hence obviously, `std::unique_ptr`. And ownees can vary in number, although they won't usually be to many, hence, a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>` works good.

At compile-time, depending on some directive, I can tell which `Agents` is `App` going to need, and which `Listener`s is each `Agent` going to need. `Agent`s to the `App`, or `Listener`s to each `Agent`, can vary in the future, but always at compile-time though, once the program is set to run nothing will change until a new version of the program is deployed.

So the question is, how can I implement all this tree-like hierarchy in an organised and future-proof way?

I tried implementing a Factory Method pattern, that will give the correct `Agent`s to the `App` (just throw in a different factory depending on the compile-time flag), but then I'm a bit stuck at how to tell the `Agent`s which `Listener`s they need in a way that is also clean. I though of again a factory of `Listener`s that take the `Agent` as a parameter, and then has a horrible switch statement querying the type of the `Agent` and giving him his `Listener`s, but that seems to get messy very quick.

PD: using VC2010, which is just partially compliant to C++11 and fully compliant to TR1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

By making your `App` responsible for creating its `Agents` and `Agents` responsible for creating their `Listeners`, you create strong dependency of the owner to the ownee that deprives you from the flexibility of choosing other kind of agents or listeners.

Using a [factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) is a good start since the factories could be provided with parameters to instantiate different kind of agents or listeners. However, it is not sufficient, since your classes would then depend on hard-wired factories instead of owned classes.

**Solutions step 1**

The solution is to use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). So instead of letting the `App` creating the `Agent`, and the `Agent` the `Listener`, you would inject the factories.

The drawback ?  As you want to be free from the bottom up dependencies and want to configure the classes to be used top down, the dependency injection would have to be multilevel.  So if you have a tree depth of 3, you'd need to inject 3 different factories for creating the App.

**Solution step 2**

Since you are creating a family of related objects, you could instead of injecting multiple factories, inject a single [abstract factory](https://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html) that would be used to create the different kind of objects.

**Solution step 3**

As you are using a kind of compile-time assembly, you could also consider a [policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). The first edition of the book that made this design popular dates back 2001, so it doesn't require C++11.

The idea is to inject a policy (aka [strategy pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html)) at compile time by using templates. This is a very powerful and flexible approach, but it requires that you switch some classes to template classes. Several scenarios are possible, for example:

- you could create a template abstract factory, and providing as policy the different classes that have to be used.
- you could also inject the type to be used at each level by having App, Agents, Listeners etc. being template classes ([simple example](https://ideone.com/sdD1gf), just to show how this could work).

One of the advantage of this approach is that template can also free you from implementing ownership with `vector<unique_ptr<...>>` and opt for plain vectors instead.

Comment: That's brilliant! Many interesting ideas here. Just one question, when you say steps you mean, all three need to be implemented one after the other, or those are three different solutions? I don't see how DI and PBD play together, don't know. I'm relatively new to both Dependency Injection and Policy-Based Design but I'm sold for learning both. About the PDB, are you refering to Alexandrescu's book Modern C++ design right? Do you have any other good material regarding that that you could recommend me? I know, I could just google, but in case you already have a favourite to share... :)
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I meant step of discovery, not a sequence for implementing (i.e. you can go immediately to the last one, if it suits your needs).  Yes, it was this book.  Other books: GoF for the patterns. And perhaps More effective C++ and Effective Modern C++ from Scott Meyers if you haven't already read them.

Comment: I always have GoF and E.M.C++ in my desk, I love those books :) I'm just wondering now, if an `Agent` has several kinds of `Listener`s, how to inject them at compile-time with a template? I'm afraid I don't have Variadic Templates here, don't know if going for Alexandrescu's typelists or something else (?)

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the `Listener` is just an interface to many kinds of listeners, therefore a vector of listeners might slice the objects, so I'll need a vector of pointers. But also, I need to figure out how to inject at compile-time this in a template... Any extra ideas? :)

Comment: @NelsonVides combining templates with pointers/smart pointers is no problem. You can even let a template class inherit from a common base class.  By the way, typelist could be an option, especially if you have a deep tree, with lots of types.  Alexandru's book shows how to implement an abstract factory using typelist.  For agents to use different kind of listeners, you'd need to explain how the different Agents know what kind of listeners to create.  But it'll go into programming issues so SO might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a data-driven approach: create some simple data format that captures the relevant details of the desired Agents (like their names), along with the details of each one's desired Listeners.

Your code would run through this simple data format and create the Agents their Listeners, and link them together.

That data can come from compile-time initialized statics if you want to build it in, or later on could come from a configuration file.

There would not necessarily be a factory method for creating `Agents` to be used by `App` — just an initialization method to create the hierarchy.  Or maybe that is the factory method though for `App` — the top level object of the hierarchy, to be returned by the factory method.